# Convert comprehensive list to an if, else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm relatively new to Python. What I try to do is convert this comprehensive list to a normal if, else statement.

```
def draw(self):
    self.value = choice(green_chars)
    self.y = self.y + self.speed if self.y < 1080 else -40 * randrange(1, 5)
    screen.blit(self.value, (self.x, self.y))
```

So far I've tried this:

```
    self.value = choice(green_chars)
    if self.y < 1080:
        self.y = self.y + self.speed 
    else:
        -40 * randrange(1, 5)

    screen.blit(self.value, (self.x, self.y))
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You forgot to assign the value in the else statement

Comment: You need to also assign self.y in the else clause.

Comment: By "comprehensive list", do you mean conditional expression?

Comment: Side-note: There are no `list`s involved here. There is no such term as "comprehensive list" in Python (I feel like you mean "list comprehension" here). The original code includes a conditional expression (sometimes called a "ternary operator", taking the form `value_on_true if conditional else value on false`), which you're converting to a plain `if` statement with an attached `else` statement, but conditional expressions have nothing to do with list comprehensions (you can use them in tandem but the result is usually pretty ugly).

Comment: @chepner: I suspect they meant "list comprehension", thinking that anything with `if` as part of an expression rather than a statement is a listcomp, not understanding that conditional expressions are something else entirely (that just happens to include `if` at the statement level as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to assign the value:

```
self.value = choice(green_chars)
if self.y < 1080:
    self.y = self.y + self.speed 
else:
    self.y = -40 * randrange(1, 5) # Here

screen.blit(self.value, (self.x, self.y))
```

Comment: Side-note: As long as they're splitting it up and requiring more repetition, they may as well make the first block do `self.y += self.speed` to avoid repeating `self.y` twice; here it doesn't matter much, but when the value being changed is more deeply nested or has a longer name, it can make the code slower and/or harder to read if you needlessly repeat the name.

Answer (score 0):

The [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) in Python is similar as other languages

```
variable = expr1 if truth-expr else expr2
```

Here `variable` will be assigned to `expr1` expression if `truth-expr` expression is true, otherwise `expr2`.

In normal form,

```
if truth-expr:
    variable = expr1
else:
    variable = expr2
```

Comment: Two things: 1) It's referred to as the conditional expression in Python, not the ternary operator (ternary operator is less precise and inaccurate; it's not an operator, and ternary would apply to anything with three operands, not just conditionals), and 2) To my knowledge, no other language uses Python's form of the operator (most C-like languages use `condition ? on_true : on_false`, the Python form of `on_true if condition else on_false` is specific to Python), so saying it's the "same as other languages" is misleading.

Comment: @ShadowRanger 1) Thanks for pointing out. I was reading the manual where it was also mentioned `sometimes called a “ternary operator”`.  But I agree `if`, `else` are not operator. I changed the wording of the answer though.  2) changed "same" -> "similar".